# parser name defined to default :"parse" warning bison after %start

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, start-of-line

I have a bison-flex project working on linux ubuntu vmPlayer, and for some reason I have  a warning I can't get off.. this is the beginning of my file, and my program (extra.y is bison file) does start with "lines":

```
%{   
   #include <stdio.h> 
   #include <stdlib.h>  
   #include <string>
   #include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
   #include <map>   
   #include <math.h>
   #include <algorithm>
   int yylex();   
   void yyerror(const char*)       
   char dollarOrWave=' ';
%}

%left OR 
%left AND
%union {
int     int_val;
char*   str_val;
}                         //THIS IS LINE 70 !!

%token<int_val> T_INT              
%token<str_val> STREXP
%type<int_val> expr   
%type<str_val> stringExp
%start lines

%%
lines:            
    line         { }//checkDollars(); }//checkDollars(); }
| lines line     { checkDollars(); numStringVarsFlag=0; }
;
```

Warning:

```
extra.y:70 parser name defined to default :"parse"
```

Searching I've seen that: [Bison grammar warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238306/bison-grammar-warnings)  but it still gives me that warning..
..HELP??

Comment: How do you call bison?  What is line 70?  Are you getting the same warning with this six-line bison file that you provided?  I presume not, as `line` is not defined.  Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: aviad@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bison$ rm -f *.h *.c *.o *.exe ; flex extra.lex ; bison -d -v extra.y    ---> this is how I call bison and this is where the warning appears.. I edited it , I can't put all my code here, its very long and I don't think its relevant since that warning started when I started the project with fewer code

Comment: I cannot reproduce the warning with your code.  Please, provide a MWE.

Comment: added some more code

Comment: An MWE is not just "some more code".  It's the least possible amount of code that when you (or anyone else) add to an empty file `extra.y` and then run `bison -d -v extra.y`, you get the warning that you mention.  With what you currently have, I can still not reproduce it and therefore I cannot help you.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found it.

Add `%name parse` before `%token`

Eg:

```
%name parse
%token NUM
```

(From: https://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/flex-bison-in-ubuntu/#comment-2669)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `bison`; you are using `bison++`. You should make that clear in your question(s) because it does make a difference.

The warning message you receive is normal in `bison++`; you can avoid it by explicitly declaring a parser class name.

From `man bison++` (assuming the documentation is correctly installed):

> `%name parser_name`
>   Declare the name of this parser. User for C++ class name, and to render many names unique. default is parse. Must be given  before `%union` and `%define`, or never.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a ';' after the `%union {}`.

```
%union {
};
```

Comment: No.  This is not the problem here (although adding a semicolon does not hurt).  Look at the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Union-Decl.html), especially the last sentence.